# populate class from ini using configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I am newbie with python , started to write some system administration utility that should read info from INI file

Now i need to init a class based of ini sections , my question how can i do that send all infoe parameters key val with following example

Please advice
Thanks

```
 class FopsTest():
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.variables = kwargs

   def set_foptype(self,FILEOP):
       self.variables['FILEOP'] = FLOPTYPE

cfgfile = os.getcwd() +'\wtrconfig.cfg'
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
try:
    os.path.exists(cfgfile)
    config.sections()
    config.read(cfgfile)
  test = FopsTest(<pass ini key,val?>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read [the documentation for the `configparser` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), it does a decent job explaining things. Be sure to read the docs for the version of Python 3 you are using though, as the interface seems to have been extended quite a bit between versions.

Starting in Python 3.2, it is possible to treat a `ConfigParser` instance as if it was a Python dictionary (the term used in the docs is the "mapping protocol"). That means, you can probably just create a class instance with `FopsTest(**config)`, or perhaps `FopsTest(**config["TheSectionICareAbout"])` if you only want the items from a specific section of the file. See [this section of the docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/configparser.html#mapping-protocol-access) for details.